# Linq: Group by Time Interval

Tags: vb.net, linq, time, intervals, linq-group

I've the following Datatable:

```
[Date];[Time];[ProcessID];[ID]
24.09.2012;08:18:00;4000;1
24.09.2012;08:18:00;4000;2
24.09.2012;08:19:00;4001;3
24.09.2012;08:23:00;4002;4
24.09.2012;08:32:00;4003;5
...
```

As result I would like to have a grouping by a 15-minute Time-Interval to count the ProcessID´s:

```
[Interval];[ProcessID Count]
8:15:00 - 8:29:00;3
8:30:00 - 8:45:00;1
```

How to achieve this goal?

Comment: Is `Date` of type `Date` and `Time` of type ...?? Why don't you use one column for both instead? What have you tried? If possible you should do it in the dbms instead.

Comment: Yes, the Date Column is a Date type and the Time Column is a Time type. I've to handle this, because it's given by my erp software.

Comment: What is a `Time` type? I only know `TimeSpan`

Comment: Yes, It´s System.TimeSpan column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution against Linq-to-SQL (on SQL Server) with the DateTime being in a single field (a LINQpad query):

```
Const BaseDate As Date = #9/24/2012#
Const PeriodMinutes As Integer = 15
Dim p = From t In TestData _
      Group By q=CInt(Math.Floor((t.SomeDate - BaseDate).TotalMinutes/PeriodMinutes)) Into Group _
      Select s=BaseDate.AddMinutes(q*PeriodMinutes), _
             e=BaseDate.AddMinutes((q+1)*PeriodMinutes), _
             ids=Aggregate g In Group Select g.ProcessID Distinct Into Count()
p.Dump
```

Using different types and other "little" adjustments could produce simpler SQL backend code.

For your actual database, you need to adjust the `Group By`, although it now depends upon what your Time column is converted to through Linq-to-SQL and/or your database's driver.

As it is a `TimeSpan` the `Group By` becomes something like:

```
 Group By d=t.[Date], q=CInt(Math.Floor(t.[Time].TotalMinutes/PeriodMinutes)) Into Group _
    Select s=d.AddMinutes(q*PeriodMinutes), _
           e=d.AddMinutes((q+1)*PeriodMinutes), _
           ids=Aggregate g In Group Select g.ProcessID Distinct Into Count()
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work (<strike>however, not tested</strike>):

```
Dim groupedByQuarter =
    From r In table
    Let day = r.Field(Of Date)("Date").Date
    Let time = r.Field(Of TimeSpan)("Time")
    Let quarter = time.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes((-1) * time.Minutes Mod 15))
    Group r By Key = New With {Key .day = day, Key .quarter = quarter} Into TimeGroup = Group
    Select New With {
        .Interval = String.Format("{0} - {1}",
                Key.quarter,
                Key.quarter.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(14))),
        .ProcessCount = TimeGroup.Select(Function(r) r.Field(Of Int32)("ProcessID")).Distinct().Count()
    }
```